# I have taken image from gallery to image view in same intent.And on image view click I want to send that image another Activity through intent.

Tags: android

**Code :**

```
 imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageDivision.class);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            i.putExtra("bmp_img", bmp);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can send imagepath with intent and decode on other activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Static `HashMap` to store the Images.
On Image click just put the image with  its name in your `HashMap` and you can get the images wherever you want just by its name.

`public static HashMap<String, Bitmap> globalImageMap;`

onImageClick:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 globalImageMap.put(name,bmp);
 Intent intent= new Intent(this, ImageDivision.class);
intent.putExtra("ImageName",name);
startActivity(i);
```

`ImageDivision.class`: just check for image by its name in `HashMap`.

```
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String s = intent.getStringExtra("ImageName");   
       if (globalImageMap.containsKey(s)) {  
                yourImageView.setImageBitmap(globalImageMap.get(s));
}
```

Comment: the `String` name of your image .. by this name you can access your image in any `Activity` of your Application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the Bitmap to a byte[] then you can convert the byte[] to the Bitmap again in your other activity..

**Bitmap to byte[]**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] ba = stream.toByteArray();

Intent intent= new Intent(this, ImageDivision.class);
intent.putExtra("bmp_image",ba);
startActivity(i);
```

**byte[] to Bitmap**

```
byte[] ba= getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bpm_image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length);
```